# How to quickly close all open terminals in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, batch-processing, kill

How to quickly close all open terminals in VS Code?

I have a lot of opened terminals and I could go over them one by one and kill each one of them separately. Or I could select a few of them and then kill the selected batch. But both approaches are not convenient, since they require a lot of time. I have at least 10000 open terminals, while in one batch I can select a few hundreds.

Is there a way to kill all terminals at once?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a `Terminal: Kill All Terminals` command, not bound to anything by default.

You could make a keybinding for it like (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+k",           // whatever you want here
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.killAll"
}
```

Or search for the command in your `Keyboard Shortcuts` page and click on the pencil icon to enter some keybinding.

```
                         Or
```

View->Command Palette-> type "kill all terminal"

```
                         Or
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> then type "kill all terminal"

[image: Command Palette: Kill All Terminals]