# how to remove all terminals in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have so many terminals in VS-Code:

[image: screenshot of terminals list]

I've clicked several times to delete them all, but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried the terminal: kill all terminals, but that didn't work either.

Comment: You can find different methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971925/how-to-quickly-close-all-open-terminals-in-vs-code).

Comment: who creates these terminals

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.